# Difference of scaled uniform distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Given $0 \le b \le a \le 1$ and also the independent r.v. $U,V \sim U(0,1)$ then I would like to derive the pdf of $Z$ where:
$$Z \sim a-b+bU-aV$$
First I derive $W \sim bU-aV$ via convolution and obtain (m is the Lebesgue measure):
$$f_w(w) = \frac{1}{ab}m([b-a,b] \cap [w,w+b])$$
Then shift this trapezoid and obtain the pdf of $Z$.
$$f_z(z) = \begin{cases} \frac{z}{ab} + \frac{1}{a}, -b \le z \le 0, \frac{1}{a}, 0 \le z \le a-b, \frac{-z}{ab} + \frac{1}{b}, a-b \le z \le a
\end{cases}$$

This integrates to $1$ but I am not sure it is the correct pdf. How can I check for correctness in this case? Is there a software package or library that can be used?